# Sign up and Sign in to azure active directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm developing a native mobile app and an application node js that I set up to authenticate by google and facebook account. I need to create new accounts to access my application and get the token to use the endpoints for people who do not have google or facebook account. Can I make a new registration and log in to azure active directory?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look at ADAL JS (i let experts responding with examples and more accurate stuff)